# ASP.NET Hide update progress control

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, hide, updateprogress

I am using UpdateProgress control of ajax as a usercontrol. It show up for all the updatePanels in the project. Sometimes i want to hide this updateProgress for specific update panels.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code

```
YourPanelContainer.Style.Add("display", "none"); //Add your control to panel or div
```

For this sample

```
<asp:Panel ID="YourPanelContainer" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="125px">

<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" >

<ProgressTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the AssociatedUpdatePanelID ="UP1" for the UpdateProgress bar.. this will make sure the progress bar shows for the ID associated with it..

This will make sure it will show up when UP1 is updated.